# Differences in database.yml in rails application,host vs socket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

What is the difference between following code in accessing mysql by host,socket ?

```
                    adapter: mysql2  
                    database: chart_development  
                    username: root
                    password: root                      
                    socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock  
                           vs
                    adapter: mysql2  
                    database: chart_development  
                    username: root
                    password: root                      
                    host: localhost
```

How to make the rails to work for both things?
"host: localhost" is not working for me.Earlier it work fine.so,I am using "socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock" right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
host: localhost
```

to

```
host: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: In which file you mean to say,sql configurations? or in rails(database.yml)?